# .NET DataGridView ScrollBar visiblechanged

Tags: c++, .net, datagridview, scrollbar

I'm creating custom datagridview control in c++/cli with dynamic colums scaling when window is resized(it fits in window 100% until some size).

Problem is how can I catch event when vertical scrollbar becomes visible? It uses some space and my dynamic scaling gets horizontal scrollbar automatically, but I want to make one of colums to be resized automatically when vertical scrollbar become visible.

Is it possible to do without implementing DataGridView::VerticalScrollBar?